# How to leave in the selection only those values that match on one line?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

There is a table that stores information about the card.

```
id_card, card_number, card_value
```

When a client issues a card, he has a choice: digital card or digital with plastic

When issuing a digital card, card_value becomes = 621

When issuing a digital card with plastic, card_value writes 2 lines 621 and 622

622 - plastic card

The task is to display only digital cards, with card_value = 621

But when I select digital cards without plastic (621), then both digital cards and digital cards with plastic are included in the selection.

This is logical because the value of the field actually contains 621 and 622.

But how to make it so as not to show records in the selection if 621 and 622 are found together?

I suppose this can be achieved with some extra column like id_card, but I doubt that's correct.

I use SQL (ORACLE 12)

Comment: Are they stored in the same field together? Like `621,622`? Could you post a minimal sample of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `card_number` will be the same for both the `621` and `622` rows then:

```sql
SELECT id_card,
       card_number,
       card_value
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         MAX(card_value) OVER (PARTITION BY card_number) AS max_card_value
  FROM   table_name t
  WHERE  card_value IN (621, 622)
)
WHERE  max_card_value = 621;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id_card, card_number, card_value) AS
SELECT 1, 11111, 621 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 22222, 621 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 22222, 622 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 33333, 621 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 33333, 555 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 44444, 621 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 44444, 622 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID_CARD | CARD_NUMBER | CARD_VALUE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 11111 | 621 |
> | 4 | 33333 | 621 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=396476e99a3c7905149b9c52503f26f4)*

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted to get.

Answer (score 0):

If 621, 622 can be in in the same field then:

`WHERE card_value NOT LIKE '%622%`

If they're separate rows, I'm going to make an assumption that there's a unique identifier for each `client` since there's no sample data in the OP.

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE unique_client_id NOT IN (SELECT unique_client_id FROM t1 where card_value = 622)
```